# Apply a policy in computer configuration for specific users in group policy

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

Is there a way in group policy (windows server 2008) to apply a policy in computer configuration for specific users?

The reason is I want to apply 'Set roaming user profile path for all users logging onto this computer' in  `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\User Profiles` but only for users logging on to the domain. I want to exclude it for local users so that if I logged into the local administrator account I get a local profile path like normal.

Comment: I would really to use a **per-user** group policy to set the roaming profile, but Microsoft didn't write the software that way.  It sucks, but I haven't found anything you can do.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do because I don't want to specify the profile paths in AD for each user. I know you can apply them for multiple users at once but I don't like it. I'd rather have it all organised in group policy.

Comment: Is the users profile path stored in the registry? Could I set it using group policy that way instead?

Comment: It is stored in the registry, but you cannot set it in the registry.  The profile is transferred and loaded before per-user group policies are evaluated.

Comment: That's annoying. How do you do it then? Do you just set them all in ad?

Comment: You either set them in AD or you set the policy computer wide. If you set it per-computer, then you basically can't have non-domain users touch that computer.  If you set the value on the user object then you have to maintain the per-user setting.  You could probably write a script that would that would periodically find and update all the user objects that belong to an OU/Group and update the setting, but that would take some effort.

Comment: @Zoredache +1 for that, it cleared it up in my head as to why it's not an option under the user settings in a GPO.

Comment: I think I might write a logon script that checks if the profile path is what it should be. Then, if it isn't, it can display a message and log back off again so that it can be sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for the most part you cannot do this.  Computer settings generally apply a setting to a service running on that computer that is completely un-related to who logs in.  For the most part it doesn't make any sense to apply a different setting per user.